# How do I search my mail and Office Communicator conversations from inside Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ms-office-communicator

I am running Office Communicator 2007 R2 and Outlook 2010 on a Microsoft Exchange Server 2010.  I am storing my conversation history from Communicator in Exchange in the default folder,  "Conversation History". I'm using the conversation view in Outlook. And I have a [Gmail-like macro](http://anthonymastrean.tumblr.com/post/5694760416/bearable-outlook) to archive my conversations to an "Archive" folder.

**I want to search all my mail and conversations at once.** By default, Outlook is searching in the current folder only.

I tried creating a rule to move the conversations to my Archive folder, but couldn't configure it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Change your Search options

After failing to configure a rule that would move all my mail into one folder (an Archive folder), I approached it differently. I figured, why change the location of the conversation? Let's change the search feature. By the way, searching in "this" folder by default required me to move to the Archive folder before searching, which itself was extra friction.

My solution was to change the Search options to search all mail items by default.

```
File | Help | Options | Search | Results | [x] All folders
```

This let's me search the Archive and Conversation History from the Inbox!